# Full Calendar day click disabled in the days in the other months

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Can I disable the selection for the day where the slot are disabled, because when I click  the day of a month ago the prompt appears, but I want to disable the selection for the other days of different month in the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work (untested!)

```
var d = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
if(new Date() => d){
  selectable: true,
}
```

Let me know